# C# Generated PDF File Does not save

Tags: email, c#-4.0

I have created a pdf file using c# code and now i want to save created pdf file into my local machine drive "E" but an error shown to me that "Access to the path 'E:\My Projects' is denied."...

here is the code to save pdf file

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"E:\My Projects", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
     FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
```

Any one please help me out....

Comment: Please give the complete code. The above code only shows where you are creating the filestream. Also, your file stream points to a folder and not a path...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have

1. `path` a string with the full qualified name and
2. `pdf` a byte[] of the generated pdf,

then just do:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(path, pdf);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx